# Python list, tuple and dictionary to JSON?

Tags: python, json, serialization, simplejson, jsonserializer

What's the best way of displaying this as JSON?

```py
{'foo': 'bar'}
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

---

My partial solution:

```py
import json

def json_tuple(*args, **kwargs):   
    if args:
        if kwargs:
            return json.dumps(args), json.dumps(kwargs)
        return json.dumps(args)

    return json.dumps(kwargs)
```

Provides:

```py
>>> json_tuple(1,2,3,4,5, **{'foo': 'bar'})
```

```json
('[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]', '{"foo": "bar"}')
```

---

Would putting the `args` list in `kwargs`—e.g.: under an `args` key—be the only solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just looking for valid JSON, you can put those values into a top-level array:

```
import json

def jsonify(*args, **kwargs):
    return json.dumps((args, kwargs))  # Tuples are faster to create
```

Which yields:

```
'[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], {"foo": "bar"}]'
```

Answer (score 1):

My "ugly" solution:

```py
import json

def jsonify(*args, **kwargs):   
    if args:
        kwargs.update({'args': args})

    return json.dumps(kwargs)
```

Provides:

```py
>>> jsonify(1,2,3,4,5, **{'foo': 'bar'})
```

```json
'{"foo": "bar", "args": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}'
```

Comment: Will fail if there's an `arg` kwarg.